# Every 2n element in nested element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to change the background color in 2n element. I've tested it but the bg-color is still blue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>nothing here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn{
                height:50px;
                width:100%;
                background:blue;
                margin-bottom:20px;
            }
            .btn:nth-child(2n){
                background:yellow;  
            }
        </style>
        <div>
            <div class="btn"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="btn"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be more like :

```
 .btn{
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        background:blue;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    div:nth-child(2n) .btn{
        background:yellow;  
    }
```

Because, in each div , there's only one .btn

nth-child works with adjacent element, not nested unfortunately :)

Comment: Thank you. But I´d like to use the class "btn" everywhere I want to. So it could be that there are two buttons inside a div or only one. But every second should have another color. Is there no way to realize it with pure CSS?

Comment: @julesdude, no, there is no “nth of a class” selector, which seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: nth-XX will count/select from element on same level / brother in HTML, it doesn't count elements through the dom like javaScript does. CSS cannot do at this time what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`.btn` is inside a div.

`.btn:nth-child(2n)` will work if your HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="btn"></div>
    <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

For your HTML structure, it should be

```
div:nth-child(2n) .btn {
    background:yellow;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aM7mD/)

Comment: Thank you. But I´d like to use the class "btn" everywhere I want to. So it could be that there are two buttons inside a div or only one. But every second should have another color. Is there no way to realize it with pure CSS?

Comment: @julesdude didnt get. can u elaborate?

Comment: The Div.btn can be anywhere in the page. It hasn´t a rule that it can only appear one time in a div-container. So I´m searching for a rule to give the button a different color every 2n. So it´s not important where the button appears.